# How to read the property from circular structured data

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Below is my code.

```
var myHttp = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var qString = require("querystring");
var fs = require('fs');

var myEvents = require('./customEvents');

var myAppWebServer = myHttp.createServer(function(request, response){

       response.writeHead(405, {'content-type':'text/html'});

       console.log(request.headers);

       response.end('{ "name":"my Name", "location":"xxx"}');        
});

myAppWebServer.listen(8080);
```

When i print response header text using console.log(request.headers) it prints the below data.

```
{ 
    host: 'localhost:8080',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'x-os-version': 'Windows 7',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    location: 'bangalore',
    'x-useragent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36',
    'x-enteringpage': 'http://localhost:8080/login',
    accept: '*/*',
    referer: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    cookie: '_ga=GA1.1.1554321962.1498024434; _gid=GA1.1.1406177709.1501568327' 
}
```

I am not sure how to print 'x-useragent' in my console. I used below syntax but throws error.

```
console.log(request.headers.x-useragent);
```

Can somebody help.

Comment: you just printed it?

 'x-useragent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36'

Comment: @yiImz: I get refernce error. Could not print the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript object key with special character have to use this way:

`request.headers["x-useragent"]`

[You can access object properties in two ways:](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

> objectName.propertyName

or

> objectName["propertyName"]

edited with chrome devtool snapshot.

[image]

Comment: I tired your syntax. It prints value as undefined.

Comment: you changed `console.log(request.headers.x-useragent);` to `console.log(request.headers["x-useragent"]);` but not working? that makes no sense to me.

Comment: tried again --- it works within Chrome devtool console. see my edited post.

Comment: But it did not work in node.js command prompt. I still get 'Undefined' value.